# FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10008]: Line 5:16 Ambiguous table alias 'in_2051_1'

Tags: hive

```
INSERT  OVERWRITE  TABLE out_2051
SELECT in_2051_0.column1,in_2051_0.column2,in_2051_1.column2,in_2051_1.column1
FROM in_2051_0
RIGHT OUTER JOIN in_2051_1 ON (in_2051_0.column2 = in_2051_1.column1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN in_2051_1 ON (in_2051_0.column2 = in_2051_1.column1)
;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10008]: Line 5:16 Ambiguous table alias 'in_2051_1'

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I can find that left and right outer join two tables with the same column means "FULL OUTER JOIN".

Change your SQL to

```
INSERT  OVERWRITE  TABLE out_2051
SELECT in_2051_0.column1,in_2051_0.column2,in_2051_1.column2,in_2051_1.column1
FROM in_2051_0
FULL OUTER JOIN in_2051_1 ON (in_2051_0.column2 = in_2051_1.column1)
```

And I think your error means the last in_2051_1 table refer is the same with the 4th line.

At the ON clause of the 5th line. the in_2051_1.column1 is ambiguous, hive dont know this in_2051_1 is the right join one or the left join one. You can give the in_2051_1 an alias like 'in_2051_1_2' at line 5.

I think the FULL OUTER JOIN is what you want.

Comment: What about two columns are different and LEFT OUTER JOIN is desired?